# Python. Problems with integrals. TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numeric

I am trying to find an array of integrate function but i have some problem with shapes and dimensions. I found coefficient k and then i found Energy for the interval x = (0,a), where a = 1 and n = (-Nmax, Nmax). I was also trying to vectorize them. But every time it gives me new errors. I'm not sure how to fix this, because i need this integrate function to call to another function to plot the graph.

```
def k_n(n):
    k = fsolve(lambda n : np.tan(n*a/2.) - np.tanh(n*a/2.),n)
    return(k)

def E(n):
    return(np.piecewise(n,[n<0.,n>=0.],
                        [lambda n: -k_n(n)**2 ,
                         lambda n: k_n(n)**2 ]))

def integrand1(x,n):
    return(np.sin(k_n(n)*x)**2)

def integrand2(x,n):
    return((np.sin(k_n(n)*a/2.))**2*(np.sinh(k_n(n)*(a-x)))**2/2*
np.exp(-a*k_n(n))*(np.sinh(k_n(n)*a/2.))**2)

def integrate(n): 
    integrand = spi.integrate.quad(integrand1,0,a/2,args=(n))+spi.integrate.quad(integrand2,a/2,a,args=(n)) 
    one = np.true_divide(1, integrand )
    return(one)
```

maybe the problem is with `n_r` and `x_r`

```
n_r = np.arange(-Nmax, Nmax,1)
x_r = np.arange(0,a,.1)

print(k_n(n_r))
print(E(n_r))
print(integrate(n_r))`
```

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.in _quad
>       return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit

Comment: @BillBell: _"which means return a tuple of length one in Python"_ - No it doesn't, that's spelt `(x,)`, not `(x)`. _"you re-define the identifier integrate in an assignment statement"_ - this doesn't actually matter either, although is poor style.

Comment: The error means that you have provided several values (a list, tuple or array) as a parameter where the function expects only one.  For example `quad` can only solve the integral for one interval, not several intervals at once.

Comment: @Eric the function k_n should return me all coeficients **k** in array in interval **-Nmax to Nmax**. Sorry about functions integrations i corrected them. I have problems with arrays and tuples but I still do not know how to rewrite it. If i make an **interval n_r** that will return me tuple with one variable it would work. But i am confused if it is possible to write like this : calling **k_n** and **integrate** functions to another.

Comment: @hpaulj , i tried to use another modules or use gaussian or for example this : **integrand = np.array([integrate(n) for n in n_r])** but then i get tuple in tuple that i do no want.

Comment: Passing an array to `integrate` passes that on to `integrand1` and `integrand2`.  The result is multiple values, matching the size of `n_r`.  That's what `quad` is choking on - it can only integrate a scalar function.

Comment: @Eric: As painful as that was, thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send an array to your function for integration. The quad function expects to have only one output from the function (like you would expect from a mathematical function). But you can iterate over the n_r array:

```
n_r = np.arange(-Nmax, Nmax,1)
x_r = np.arange(0,a,.1)

print(k_n(n_r))
print(E(n_r))
print(np.array([integrate(n) for n in n_r]))
```

The result is a two-dimentional numpy array.

Comment: I tried it as well, it works but then yes exactly i will have a two-dimentional numpy array. And i use the integrate function to call it in last function to plot a graph. So for example here if i write `integrate = np.array([integrate(n) for n in n_r])` and call it for example to function fun(n,r) i will get norm1 but i cant get norm2 becuause of different shapes. 
`def fun(x,n): 
norm 1 = np.sqrt(integration)
norm2 = norm1 * np.sin(x)
`
But thank you, I guess, I need to ude another method but quad in integration or write it numerically :)

Comment: What form of the result do you need? What do you mean by norm1 and norm two? And what shapes are not the same? I feel that it is more a problem of transformation than a problem of quad function. For one value you get one result in quad function. For two variables with ranges you receive a matrix. Sounds exactly what I would expect from an interaction function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
np.vectorize()
```

to create a vectorized version of the integral function.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(t, n, x):
    return np.exp(-x*t) / t**n

def expint(n, x):
    return quad(integrand, 1, np.inf, args=(n, x))[0]

vec_expint = np.vectorize(expint)
```

an example would be

```
>>>vec_expint(3, np.arange(1.0, 4.0, 0.5))
array([ 0.1097,  0.0567,  0.0301,  0.0163,  0.0089,  0.0049])
```

In case you are wondering, this example is given [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/integrate.html)